# Atlassian SourceTree does not show remote branches?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am running SourceTree 1.6.11 on windows. I have cloned a Git repository but it does not show my remote branches:

[image]

Does SourceTree only show local branches?

It shows all the tags though.

Answer (score 43):

I found this to checkout a remote branch:

Repository > Checkout > Checkout New Branch > Checkout remote branch [select remote branch to checkout]

The branch I selected is now shown in the menu on the left under branches, (although still not in the branches dropdown box along the top)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this and none of the solutions here worked for me. What did work was in my SourceTree repository, press the Settings button to get the Repository Settings dialog. Then press the Edit Config File button and open the config file. Then changed the fetch line under [remote "origin"] to this, saved the file, fetched and the remote branches then showed up.
Before:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

After:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Apply the above solution and press fetch again in sourcetree.

Comment: This did the trick! None of the other solutions worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

This is an old post but I thought as I got here, others may too
I had this issue in 1.6.2 Source tree (in Oct 2015) and my new remote made on another machine 5 days ago was not showing up in Source Tree on my work machine. I can see my remote branch with command line and in BitBucket web site but not in SourceTree.

Anyway, after ten minutes of doing nothing my remote branch showed up.

I then found in options that there is a setting for refreshing remotes which not surprisingly was set to 10 minute intervals.

On top of this it is possible to refresh immediately with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Hope this helps someone.

Dave

Comment: Thank you for this!  BTW, for SourceTree on the Mac, the key to refresh remote branches immediately is CTRL+ALT+R.

Answer (score 8):

The solution for me was simple. Simply use the command line, and execute

```
git branch -r
```

and

```
git branch -a
```

to make sure you have all the remote branches locally, then checkout each branch which is NOT showing in sourcetree. After you check it out, it will display in sourcetree.

For instance, after executing

```
git checkout develop
```

your develop branch will display in sourcetree.

Comment: -1 Most people who come to this question know how to do it on the command line, they were interested specifically with Sourcetree

Answer (score 7):

What wound up working for me, after some trial and error, was to:

- copy the path of my remote
- remove the remote from my repo settings
- let my project refresh in SourceTree
- add the remote back, in repo settings
- perform a Fetch

The Fetch alone didn't seem to do the trick, in and of itself, for each repository I experienced the issue in (it happened in a small handful, and a Fetch alone did work for some).

Expanded info:

What seems to be at issue here is how the local repository was tracking the remote. For those that a simple Fetch did *not* resolve the issue, running `git branch -r` in the repository yielded nothing. After successfully being able to view them, I confirmed the output of `git branch -r` output the *HEAD* along with *master* and *develop* branches for my remote, as I expected.

Comment: Bizarre, my colleague just had the same issue and I had already tried removing and readding the remote, but the important part seemed to be to close the repo settings window and let SourceTree do a refresh before opening the settings again and adding the remote back in.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue .refresh didn't work.so i manually fetch from the remote

Just run this command and restart sourcetree

```
git fetch --all
```

Answer (score 3):

SourceTree does show remote branches. It seems like your remote repository only has a branch `master`. Compare the output of `git branch -r`, which lists all remote branches. Try `git fetch` if your remote copy is out of sync.

Comment: No there are around 30 branches I can list them with git show-ref but ok thought it was strange/a bug that they did not show up in SourceTree.

Comment: If they are there, they should show up. Can you show us the output of `git branch -r`?

Answer (score 1):

(This probably is not your issue but it is easy to end up here with certain search queries.)

Make sure you perform a `fetch` on the remote repo. This may take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turns out the repo I was attempting to push to was not assigned to the team I was given rights to work as a part of. My admin moved the repo to our team and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few of the above examples with no luck so here is what I did. In BitBucket, go to the branch you want to check out and press the beautiful blue "Checkout in SourceTree" button.

Next I went to SourceTree and instead of clicking Branches, which one would think being a newbie, click remotes on the left side. Open up your tree views until you find the branch you want to access and double click. A dialog should pop up to create a new branch, Go ahead and press ok. Your BitBucket branch should now be in your local and be showing in the Branch side menu.

If this is completely wrong or the incredibly slow way let me know but it worked when all else didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different things like upgraded the source tree, restart , clear cache and all other things. does not work for me. However Following step solved my problem. It is look like source tree bug which is already reported multiple times.

- Open Terminal from Source Tree
- write following command with your current branch name
- git push --set-upstream origin #BRANCHNAME

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I didn't see the little checkbox "Show Remote Branches" in top bar in SourceTree :-)